# Deposited a 1m Life Ins. benefit check to WF. Do you foresee any issue dividing it up in 1/4?

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, insurance

Deposited a 1m Life Ins. benefit check to Wells Fargo. Do you foresee any issue dividing it up in 1/4 by opening three other accounts and either writing a check or wire to move? Concerned with any issues moving a large sum and FDIC coverage (and all eggs in one basket-living trust and investments come a little later).

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: My only opinion is that you'll probably want to stick to wire transfers and not a different form of money transfer.

Comment: I'm assuming you personally knew the person who died. If so, I'm truly sorry for your loss. Make sure you take your time; this is a lot of money and likely an emotional time for you. However, just in case... if you didn't personally know the person who died, be aware this could be a scam. Please ask a new question if that's the case, and we can give you warning signs to watch for.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's your money and you should be able to move it where you want, except that in the very short-term Wells Fargo probably has some standard holding period of several days on the initial deposit to make sure that the check clears.

There's no real reason to prefer wire, ACH, check, etc. other than personal preference and the requirements of wherever you're making the deposit.  Wire and ACH will probably clear faster, so if that's a concern use them. On the other hand, they probably incur some fees, so that might make you prefer the check.

Comment: I see the answer that came later by @mhoran_psprep, who makes a good point about FDIC coverage. I understood your question to mean that you're opening accounts at different banks, in which case you get separately insured. If all at the same bank, see his answer too.

Answer (score 4):

Moving it to three other accounts may not be enough, if they are all your accounts and all in the same bank.

Now if one is yours; and one is joint with another person; and one is a retirement account, and one is fully owned by that other person. Then you have separate accounts as viewed by FDIC.

Now if that won't work for you then moving the money to a another branch might work if they are viewed by the government as separate banks. But that might not work unless the corporation is structured that way. It may also require that the other branch be in a different state so that it is deposited with the other corporation.

Your best approach would be separate institutions: some could be banks, some could be credit unions, some could even be investment companies as long as it was deposited into  an FDIC protected account.

Work with the other banks to see how they want to make the transfer. The money is significant enough that they will be more than helpful.

Note: some bank/credit unions have some accounts that don't carry FDIC coverage. These have higher interest rates, but lack the protection.

Comment: Thanks all, I have another question and will create a new one soon. The person was very dear to me and I'm financially ignorant and have children to think of first. Don't reply here as I'll post it later tonight.